# Laws of logic Assertion/Reason format

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am taking a Discrete Math class and we have this question.

> $(B-A) \cup (C-A) = (B \cup C) -A$

Our section notes barely gloss over this, and *Discrete Mathematics and Its Application, 7th Edition* by Kenneth Rosen, glosses over it also. I would just like some guidance on how to solve this.

My [course notes](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~pkirby/mad2104/SlideShow/CourseNotesMAD2104.pdf), page 104, example 1.11.2 has an example but not much else.

Comment: That is not a question but rather an identity. I'm assuming the exercise is to show that this identity holds? Have you talked about showing identities of sets by showing subset relations (i.e. $A=B$ iff $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$)?

Comment: We have instruction videos and our professor is not great on answering questions. I am in a Distance Learning class.

Comment: Draw Venn diagrams.

Comment: @fleablood ugh please don't. They might be a reasonable method of visualizing some things (though I personally don't really like them) but as a method of proof they are sorely lacking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prove the identity
$$
(B - A) \cup (C - A) = (B \cup C) - A \tag{=}
$$
prove that each side is a subset of the other:
$$
\begin{align}
(B - A) \cup (C - A) &\subseteq (B \cup C) - A \tag{⊆} \\
(B - A) \cup (C - A)  &\supseteq (B \cup C) - A  \tag{⊇} \\
\end{align}
$$
You can do this by reasoning about elements. Membership in a term involving Boolean operations turns into a statement involving "and", "or" and "not", which you can manipulate as a statement of propositional logic using the analogous rules (De Morgan's laws, and so on.)

To show (⊆): suppose $x \in (B - A) \cup (C - A)$. Then $x$ is in $B-A$ or $x$ is in $C-A$; equivalently, ($x \in B$ and $x \notin A$) or ($x \in C$ and $x \notin A$); equivalently, ($x \in B$ or $x \in C$) and $x \notin A$; this last is equivalent to: $x \in (B \cup C) - A $.

Similarly, to show (⊇): if $x \in (B \cup C) - A$, then $x \in B \cup C$ and $x \notin A$; equivalently, ($x \in B$ or $x \in C$) and $x \notin A$; etc. It's basically reversing the steps of the other inclusion just proved.

Answer (score 2):

I'll do my best to help, but I have never taken a discrete math course, so don't blame me if it isn't of much help :P

Consider $B-A$. By definition, $B-A = \{b\ |\ b \in B, b \notin A\}$. Now consider $C-A$. By definition, $C-A = \{c\ |\ c \in C, c \notin A\}$. Applying the definition of the union, this would mean that $(B-A) \cup (C-A)=\{x\ |\ x \in (B \cup C), x \notin A\}$.

By definition, $(B∪C)−A = \{x\ |\ x \in (B \cup C), x \notin A\}$. This means that $(B-A) \cup (C-A) = (B∪C)−A$.

$QED$